# Limesurvey -- How can I verify from a custom Java app that a user has completed a survey?

Tags: api, integration, limesurvey

Using LimeSurvey 1.90, I want to be able to check from a custom Java application if a user has completed a survey defined in LimeSurvey. I found [this](http://docs.limesurvey.org/tiki-index.php?page=Results+API+-+Access+Control), but it looks like it applies to version 2, not version 1.9.

I don't care about any other information from the survey, other than if the user has completed it or not.  Has anyone done this type of integration?

Any/all replies are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same question posted on the LimeSurvey forum. According to the experienced users/moderators of the forum, the only way to integrate with LS 1.9 is via direct DB integration. Any queries written against 1.0 will be invalid for LS2 as the DB schema is changing.

Answer (score 1):

Limesurvey allows you to set a URL for a page that the survey redirects to after completion. Build a URL that has sufficient information in the GET parameters that your Java app will be able to parse and record.